# Prism MVVM pattern: View is always one step behind on property change in ViewModel

Tags: vb.net, mvvm, windows-store-apps, prism, inotifypropertychanged

In Prism , MVVM, Windows 8.1 StoreApp I want the ViewModel to capture the SelectItem in a ListView. The ListView contains an ObservableCollection of objects. The ViewModel needs to lookup more details of the selected object and notify the View. The View in turn should show the details of the object.

**I have implemented this, but the View allways shows the former object (after selecting a new one)**

Of course what I'm looking for is an immediate and correct reaction in the View on selecting an object. Here are my codesnippets, all in VB code.

**EDIT:** I have put up another - smaller- example, using this approach. I made a recording of the process [in this video.](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=56CCD1B71E24988D!43360&authkey=!AAlbFK1adWoFhTA&ithint=video%2Cwmv) **Please take a look at it before you read further!!**

The objects come from the ViewModel as:

> Public Property Persons As New ObservableCollection(Of Person)

They are bound to a usercontrol:

```
<Grid>
    <ListView 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" 
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource BusinessCard}">
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <Behaviors:ListViewSelectionChangedAction/>
            </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Via the Behavior eventually this ends up in the ViewModel through this code:

```
Sub New(InjectedEventAggregator As IEventAggregator)

        LocalEventAggregator = InjectedEventAggregator
        LocalEventAggregator.GetEvent(Of PersonIsSelectedEvent)().Subscribe(AddressOf HandlePersonIsSelected, True)
```

This event is handled by this routine

```
    Public Sub HandlePersonIsSelected(ByVal SelectedPerson As Person)
        ActualPerson = SelectedPerson
    End Sub
```

The last part of all this is the property that contains the ActualPerson like so:

```
    Private Property _ActualPerson As Person
    Public Property ActualPerson As Person
        Get
            Return _ActualPerson
        End Get
        Set(value As Person)
            SetProperty(_ActualPerson, value)
        End Set
    End Property
```

**EDIT:** and this is the XAML that should show the selected ActualPerson:

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding ActualPerson}" >

       <Image Source="{Binding Photo}" Stretch="Fill" />

       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding FamilyName}" />
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Gender}" />
       </StackPanel>

</StackPanel>
```

When I step through the code, I can see that the SelectedItem event is caught in the ViewModel, the handler for the selected person is called, the property is updated. Using Prism this would also mean, that the NotifyPropertyChanged event is fired. It IS fired indeed, otherwise the former object would not show either I guess.

But why is the View not updated immediatelty with the right (Person) object?

If you have a clue.... be my honored guest!

Regards

Comment: You have not shown the code for 'The View in turn should show the details of the object'. If the XAML code is bound to the ActualPerson object, it should show the ActualPerson's details. Can you try binding the Text property of a TextBlock to the ActualPerson.<Any Property> and check what you are seeing.

Comment: @Wonderfulworld Thanks for your reaction. I have made an edit in the Original post. The selected object from the listview IS a person. Based on that, the ActualPerson property is refreshed. The problem is not the binding as such, but the timing: only the former object is COMPLETELY shown. Binding to other properties works, but with the same lag in reaction: Always the object that was chosen on the previous click.

Comment: Your code looks correct to me. As soon as 'ActualPerson = SelectedPerson' is called, the UI will be updated. Unless the ActualPerson is the former object, you should see the recently clicked person. Put a break point inside the Set operation of the ActualPerson and see whether it is called twice, and is anyone setting back the latest object to the former object.

Comment: @wonderfulworld Thanks for your reply. I fully agree with you that the code looks OK, but that's exactly my problem!! I don't see why it does not work correctly. I have put a break on the setter as you suggested and see that it passes ONCE through there. Stepping further, the Prism library functions take over (via SetProperty) and I can assure that the BindableBase class raises PropertyChanged. Stil.... no reaction on the View.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to understand what you said in "no reaction on the View". Are you saying the UI is NOT CHANGED, even though the 'ActualPerson = SelectedPerson' is called?

The controls have a binding property called MODE which decides the data flow. The [MODE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode(v=vs.110).aspx) for the TextBlocks that display the Person information can be **OneWay**. It is possible that the binding is **OneTime** which is causing the issue.

Comment: You understand it correct!. There is NO reaction on the View. And YES the ActualPerson  = SelectedPerson is called, and YES the Set - SetProperty in the ActualPerson property is called as well. This is why I am pulling my hair out and banging it to the wall. I cannot figure out what is wrong. As far as I know OneWay binding is the default. I have changed to OneWay. No difference in behaviour.

Comment: @wonderfulworld To make it easeier to see what is happening, I have constructed another small example. See the first edit in the Original posting. You can also take a look [here] (https://prismwindowsruntime.codeplex.com/discussions/564825) to see the complete discussion about this.

Comment: Have you tried calling SetProperty(_Messages, value, "Messages")? The last parameter is the property rather than the field.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please confirm what is coming from your Repository? I'm assuming it isn't an observable collection. At least it shouldn't be, I'd think it would be a serialisable POCO object. This means that you will need to add the items to the observable collection. The way I do this if not using a CollectionView is to have a readonly variable of type ObservableCollection, which is never changed. Then when you make the request to messages, I would ensure the collection is cleared, ready for new the new items. Once the messages are returned, loop through each model item (message) within the response and convert them to MessageViewModels (a new class that contains bindable properties and validation (data annotations) as required. As each ViewModel item is created it is added to the observablecollection. The act of adding items to the collection will raise an event the listview is listening for and therefore will display the item (as long as the MessageViewModel has an associated data template.

```
private readonly _messages = new ObservableCollection<MessageViewModel>(); 

Public ObservableCollection<MessageViewModel> Messages {get { return _messages;}}
```

OnNavigateTo

```
Messages.Clear; 
foreach(var message in await _messageRepository,GetMessagesAsync()) 
{ 
    Messages.Add(new MessageViewModel(){Name = message.Name, Text = message.Text}); 
}
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: You can be sure that what comes from the repository is an observablecollection<Message>. The conversion from the raw json data into something usable in the ViewModel layer is completely done in the repository. I have had a lot of help from this suggestion you make here, and came up with a final working solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One bad solution, but maybe it is helpful. You can call "again" OnProperyChanged. I say "again" because it is supposed that SetProperty calls it, but I am having some issues with VB.NET and SetProperty too.

```
Private Property _ActualPerson As Person
Public Property ActualPerson As Person
    Get
        Return _ActualPerson
    End Get
    Set(value As Person)
        SetProperty(_ActualPerson, value)
        OnPropertyChanged("ActualPerson")
    End Set
End Property
```

Edited 04/02/15: the good solution is here: [OnPropertyChanged not fired when SetProperty is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27379006/onpropertychanged-not-fired-when-setproperty-is-called)

As simple as removing the word "Property" in the private declaration. It is because it is passed ByRef, so it cannot be a property.