# OnPropertyChanged not fired when SetProperty is called

Tags: vb.net, prism

I am using Prism 5 and Visual Basic, but I guess a solution in C# would be also valid for me.

The problem I have is that this code works fine:

```
Private Property _nombreEnvio As String
Public Property nombreEnvio As String
    Get
        Return _nombreEnvio
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        SetProperty(_nombreEnvio, value)
        OnPropertyChanged("nombreEnvio")
    End Set
End Property
```

But if I remove the line that calls OnPropertyChange, it does not update the fields in the view:

```
Private Property _nombreEnvio As String
Public Property nombreEnvio As String
    Get
        Return _nombreEnvio
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        SetProperty(_nombreEnvio, value)
        ' THIS CODE DOES NOT REFRESH THE VIEW
    End Set
End Property
```

It is supposed that the SetProperty call should call the OnPropertyChanged, but it does not. It has a strange behaviour where it updates the view with the last value. And I explan myself, because it is complicated:

- If nombreEnvio is CARLOS, and I set it to PEDRO, it does not update the view, it remains showing CARLOS.
- If then I set it to ANTONIO, it shows PEDRO in the view
- If then I set it to MIGUEL then it shows ANTONIO in the view
- And so on... always the last value, not the one set now

And just adding the OnPropertyChanged line, it works fine.

Can anyone explain me why could it be?

Thank you very much

**UPDATED 30/01/2015**
I have created a new VB project (named TestPrismVB), installed Prism and I have written this simple code:

```
Imports Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm

Public Class pruebaViewModel
    Inherits BindableBase

    Private Property _oneProperty As String
    Public Property oneProperty As String
        Get
            Return _oneProperty
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            SetProperty(_oneProperty, value)
            'IF I UNCOMMENT THIS LINE, IT WORKS:
            'OnPropertyChanged("oneProperty")
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Property _anotherProperty As String
    Public Property anotherProperty As String
        Get
            Return _anotherProperty
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            SetProperty(_anotherProperty, value)
            oneProperty = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

And the XAML file is MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TestPrismVB"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:pruebaViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding anotherProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBlock Text ="{Binding oneProperty}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

If you run this simple project, and you type 1234, you will see that the TextBlock updates one step behind (it will show 123 instead of 1234).

Is it a VB bug? A Prism bug? Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not familiar with Prism, but aren't you supposed to call OnPropertyChanged like the first snippet?  Just from looking at this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I think it is the NO-Prism way. Take a look at this blog, it is very well explained: http://blog.pluralsight.com/async-validation-wpf-prism. Thank you

Comment: More data: I have tested the DoSomething function explained here, http://10rem.net/blog/2013/02/25/using-callermembername-for-property-change-notification-in-xaml-apps, and the CallerMemberName works fine. I have no idea what can be wrong.

Comment: How is you XAML bound to it? Could you post that as well? 

OnPropertyChanged is going to flag to the UI that it needs to re-pull the 'get' again. I don't know what your SetProperty() method is doing, but from what I can tell it looks like it is eventually calling OnPropertyChanged, but probably before you change the property (so it is telling the UI to update before you actually update the value, which is pulling the 'old' value).

The blog linked is using delegate methods that eventually call OnPropertyChanged. I simply call it in all my Setters and have never had an issue, why leave it out?

Comment: Here you have the XAML code, @TrialAndError: `<TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding nombreEnvio}" Style="{StaticResource campoTexto}"  />`. The SetProperty() method isn't mine, it is the Prism SetProperty() method, I have not changed it in anyway. Thank you

Comment: Some suggestions: 1) set a breakpoint in your property setter just before `SetProperty()` is called and inspect what are the values of `_nombreEnvio` and `value` - do they differ? 2) inspect the return value of the `SetProperty()` method - if it is false, the event has not been raised because the new value equals the old one. If the values differ and the method returns true, we need to investigate deeper. Perhaps there's something wrong with your view model or view...

Comment: I have done both suggestions of @dymanoid. 1) Both values are the correct ones, _nombreEnvio has current nombreEnvio and value has the new one we want to set. They are the correct values and they differ. 2) It returns TRUE, but the view is not updated if I do not call OnPropertyChanged. Thank you anyway for your suggestions.

Comment: @CarlosAdrián, well, there's one more thing you can check. Do subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event of your view model inside itself, for example, in constructor: `this.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => { var name = e.PropertyName; return; };` (this is C# syntax, you have to translate it into VB.NET). Then set the breakpoint on the `return` statement. If your event gets fired, then you'll reach this breakpoint. If not, then we have a bug in Prism while using it with VB.NET :)

Comment: @dymanoid, I have typed this code `AddHandler Me.PropertyChanged, Function(s, e)
                                           Dim name = e.PropertyName
                                           Return Nothing
                                       End Function
` and it DOES STOP in the return for e.PropertyName = nombreEnvio. Maybe a bug for VB? Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Well, all this does confirm that Prism works. So the problem is caused by your view bindings or something else. The ‛PropertyChanged‛ event actually gets fired.

Comment: However it refreshes always one step behind, not with the new value but with the previous one. Any other ideas to test? What can be wrong in my view binding?

Comment: @dymanoid Thank you for your help, but I am not able to understand it. How can my view bindings be wrong if they refresh when I call OnPropertyChanged?

Comment: @dymanoid, I have updated the question, so you can reproduce the bug. Am I doing something wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I can help you now. I'm not a Visual Basic developer, so I didn't see the "error" in your code, but an experienced VB.NET specialist could help you in 5 minutes.

So Prism and Visual Basic do all the things exactly as they should do, the issue is caused by your code, and this line is responsible for it:

```
Private Property _oneProperty As String
```

The `SetProperty()` method accepts the property storage `ByRef`, but you provide a **property** as a storage. In this case, when you pass a **property** as a `ByRef` parameter, VB copies the property value to a temporary variable, passes **the variable** `ByRef` and assigns back the value in the variable to the property.

The observed behavior has a simple explanation: Prism raises the `PropertyChanged` event and WPF binding requests the new property value **just before** it will be assigned by VB from the temporary variable which has been actually passed `ByRef`.

**TL;DR** The solution is:

Replace this

```
Private Property _oneProperty As String
Private Property _anotherProperty As String
```

with this

```
Private _oneProperty As String
Private _anotherProperty As String
```

Comment: As simple as that, and I was going mad. Thank you very much, this is the correct solution.